# create table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error when I attempt to run this query:

```
create table New_Table as  
select NAme  
from File_name, FileType  
where File_name.name = FileType.Name
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
"ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 2
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Specify which `name` are you selecting. `file_name.name` or `filetype.name`?

Comment: The ambiguous column name won't be helping, if it's like that in your real query. But it sounds like it might be a data dictionary problem, possibly with `DUAL`; the error looks like it's coming from a system trigger. How may rows id `DUAL` reporting, and is there a trace file from the 604 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `NAme` a separate field from `file_name.name` and `filetype.name`?  If not, you would need to specify `file_name.name` or `filetype.name` in your `SELECT` statement.